# Prevent certain library APIs from being used inside my project (c#)

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm looking for a way to prevent certain C# library APIs from being called. Here is an example.

There is a static class [`PromptDialog`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs) with method `Choice`. It accepts parameters for users to pick from a set of options. Also, this API accepts optional parameter `tooManyAttempts` to handle the case when the user exceeds the number of attempts allowed.

We want to always gracefully handle the case where the # of retries is exceeded, which is why we wrapped `PromptDialog.Choice` into a method that always handles this case.

**The problem:** how do we lock `PromptDialog.Choice` API and prevent it from being used in our codebase to avoid situations when exceeded retries case is not handled? We don't have control of the code that implements `PromptDialog.Choice`. Hopefully this can be done at compile time to warn the developers of possible missed scenarios.

I've come across similar requirement multiple times within a project, but wasn't able to find a good solution. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: C# and the .NET ecosystem is not designed to work this way.  Your best bet is to provide adequate documentation and warnings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you have an idea of how I can add a warning, that would help too

Comment: What will happen if exceeding the number of retries is not handled gracefully? What is the specific risk you are trying to mitigate?

Comment: @DanWilson, in this specific case the current ongoing task will be interrupted by an exception and the context of the conversation will be lost. That said, prompt dialog is just one example demonstrating the need to block APIs from external libraries.

Comment: You add a warning by putting it into your developer documentation.  Feel free to add any marking you wish to identify the text as a "warning."

Comment: Is it possible to add `[Obsolete("seriously, be careful", false)]` to the method ? then just add `#pragma warning disable CS0618` and `#pragma warning restore CS0618` around the few places where you *meant* to use it? I'm not sure what it says about me that I didn't need to look up that error number...

Comment: @MarcGravell, we cannot add `Obsolete` attribute to the `PromptDialog` class, since it is a library class we consume from an assembly. It is also not partial, hence we cannot have a part of it in our codebase to mark it as obsolete.

Comment: I’d love to do this too: some sort of external linting tool which fails the build if developers use certain APIs. This Software Engineering StackExchange question has a few interesting answers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358951/forbid-calls-to-arbitrary-functions-classes-in-external-code

Answer (score -1):

If this is for an internal project, I suggest wrapping the `Choice` call or the entire `PromptDialog` class in a internal wrapper that can enforce these cases and to update all internal uses of those to this new wrapper.

```
class ExternalClass
{
    public int ExternalMethod(int input)
    {
        // do a thing
    }
}

public class WrapperClass
{
    private ExternalClass external;

    public WrapperClass(ExternalClass external)
    {
        this.external = external;
    }            

    public int WrapperMethod(int input) {
        // do the verification or checks that you need here
        return this.external(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's already done. I want to restrict developers on my project from using `ExternalClass` from anywhere except a wrapper.